# unique dimensions for fact indexing

Tags: iccube

I'm getting the following error in the icCube log:
[BUILDER_LINE_TABLE_ON_PROCESS_LINE] Data table '_Interval_Info (buffer)', line '1' : Member key '1' (with name '2013.12.29 00:00') is not unique for fact indexing level '[Time].[Time].[Minute]', colliding member '[Time].[Time].[All-M].&[2013].&[Dec-13].&[2013-12-29].&[2013.12.29 00:00].&[1], Name :2013.12.29 00:00, Key :1' location: :

The cube is using partitioning and the _Interval_Info table's data source is a CSV file. With each partition, the incremental load strategy for this table is a full reload.  It seems from the error that the colliding member is the same as the member in question but maybe this is tied to something else? Is there a way for me to further diagnose the issue? If I load the failing partition into an empty cube, the load works without error so this is somehow tied to having certain other partitions in the cube.

thanks

Comment: It's likely the parents are different, the coming version (next week) will have an improved log